# Getting an error when trying to assign a data controller to a UICollectionViewController in XCode

Tags: objective-c, ios, controller, uicollectionview

I've set up a LibraryDataController class that gets data from an sqlite database. This is its .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface LibraryDataController : NSObject{
    sqlite3 *database;
}
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *masterPhotoList;

-(NSInteger)listCount;
-(NSString*)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
-(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded;
-(void)initializeDefaultList;
-(void)closeDatabase;
@end
```

I also have a library view that has a LibraryDataController member:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class LibraryDataController;
@interface LibraryViewController : UICollectionViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) LibraryDataController *dataController;

@end
```

My problem occurs on the app startup where I load information from the sqlite database into a data controller (The init function does this successfully). Then I try to assign the database to the library view. The library view is the second view on a tab bar, and the tab bar controller is the root view.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    LibraryViewController *libraryView = [[tabController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    LibraryDataController *aDataController = [[LibraryDataController alloc] init];

    libraryView.dataController = aDataController;

    return YES;
 }
```

The error comes from the libraryView.dataController = aDataController; line. Any ideas about what my problem is? I'm thinking it may have to do with the UICollectionView as I am very new to it. This code is almost identical to code I used successfully with a UITableView and I was under the impression the two views were very similar. Thanks for your help.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: @martin This is what I get: `2012-12-07 02:38:03.320 iPhone AR[10244:11303] -[UICollectionViewController setDataController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71a5170
2012-12-07 02:38:03.614 iPhone AR[10244:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewController setDataController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71a5170'`

Comment: That means that `libraryView` is an instance of `UICollectionViewController`, and not `LibraryViewController`, as you expect. If the controller is defined in a nib or storyboard file, you probaby have to set the "Custom Class" to "LibraryViewController".

Comment: Thanks Martin! Storyboard sure does make me miss the little things sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

```
[UICollectionViewController setDataController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71a5170
```

shows that `libraryView` (which is the second view controller of the tab bar controller) is an instance of `UICollectionViewController`, and not `LibraryViewController`, as you expected.

The solution is to set the "Custom Class" of the view controller in the storyboard file to "LibraryViewController" (using the "Identity inspector).